# How do I use `Mono.zip(Iterable<? extends Mono<?>> monos, Function<? super Object[],? extends R> combinator)`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to use this function:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.function.Function-

Because the customer sends me what call to WebClient I should make in a form of `List<Supplier<Mono<? extends Response>>>` ( `Response` being an interface all kind of response implements), I have to execute those calls in parallel, but instead of the response from the request, I receive an `Object[]`

And obviously, I can't do anything with this without downcasting into an actual response, but I only know at runtime what kind of response it is.

Here is my code :

```
var requests = x.preRequests()
         .getSteps()
         .stream()
         .map(Supplier::get)
         .toList();

// response is an instance of Object, I can't use the method of the interface
return Mono.zip(requests, objects -> Arrays.stream(objects).map(object -> object.responseMethod()))
```

I can't call the method because I end up with an instance of `Object`

Do you have an idea of how I can get back the actual response returned by each of the request ?

Thank you

Comment: Please show your actual code instead of describing it in abstract terms. Having real code makes answer questions so much easier and so much more helpful to feature visitors.

Comment: You're right, I modified the post

Comment: What type do you expect your output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good workaround, If you have a list of `Mono<T>` and you want to zip them.

Just use `Flux.merge(List<Mono<T>>)` and all your requests will be executed. And you will not lose the type of `T`

Here is the example that helped me understand :

```java
      public static void main(String[] args){
        var list = List.of(get(), get(), get());
    
        Mono.zip(list, (objects) -> Arrays.stream(objects).collect(Collectors.toList()) ).subscribe(nameList -> System.out.println("from mono: " + nameList));
        Flux.merge(list).collect(Collectors.toList()).subscribe(nameList -> System.out.println("from flux: " + nameList));
    
        Util.sleepSeconds(5);
      }
    
    
      private static Mono<String> get() {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> Util.faker().name().fullName()).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
      }
```

Both `Mono.zip` and `Flux.merge` takes 2s to get response from the mono